# VB.Net HTML Indentation Function

Tags: html, vb.net, pretty-print

Not having much luck "googling" this as they assume I want to do it online.

Are the any built in function inside VB.net that takes a string

```
Private Function PrettyPrintHTML(byval str as string) as string

 'Do Pretty Things Here

  Return PrettyThing

End Function
```

EG

```
<html><head><title>Value</title></head><body><div><label>Username:<input id="Username"/></label></div></body></html>
```

And will output with the indentations in the correct place, i.e

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Value</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label> Username: 
        <input id="username"/>
      </label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to output the correctly formatted string to the screen.

Comment: Are you talking about from a programming point of view (e.g. your code should change this string), or from an IDE point of view (e.g. you want to nicely format your code in Visual Studio)?

Comment: Code :) I'll edit the question

Comment: Pity, because I could have helped with the other one.  I'm not aware of anything built in (but that doesn't mean there isn't something, maybe a 3rd party component).